# how to show posts on different pages if number of post per page is one

Tags: posts, categories, pagination

i have a category named "services". when "our services" is clicked control go to category.php file. in that i need to show all the posts in that service category. i can show all of them in a single page. but i need to show them with pagination where there should be one post per page. i use the below portion to give pagination.

```
<div class="content-inner">
                    <?php global $cat_name;
     $cat_name = get_category(get_query_var('cat'))->name;
     echo '<h2 class="entry-title">'.$cat_name.'</h2>';

     ?>
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : 

                        ?>
                    <?php query_posts('category_name='.$cat_name.'&posts_per_page=1&order=ASC'); ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>

         <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

             <br><br>  <div class="popthumb"><h3>

                     <li type="square">  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php //the_title(); ?>"><?php //the_post_thumbnail(); ?><?php  the_title(); ?></a></li>

                 </h3>


 </div>

 <div class="popcontent">
 <?php the_excerpt();?> 

    </div><br>

    </article><br><br>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
<div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Next &raquo;') ?></div>
```

i have totally 3 posts in the service category.as per the code it shows only one post per page. but when i click next page not found error is occuring. what should i do?

Comment: I would avoid using `query_posts` - better change the main query with `pre_get_posts` - see [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Comment: if that code is on category.php, why are you adding a query at all? as @ptriek already suggested, work with `'pre_get_posts'` to set the number to 1 post per page, or set this number generally under ***settings - reading***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, never use `query_posts()`, use `WP_Query()` instead. ([Learn More](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts))

With your `WP_Query()` use `paged` parameter in the argument array, like:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'paged' => $paged
);

$cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

And for the pagination link, go with:

```
<?php
$total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
if ( $total_pages > 1 ) { ?>

    <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">

        <div class="nav-previous">
            <?php next_posts_link(__( '<span class="meta-nav">&laquo;</span> Older Entries', 'your-theme' )) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-next">
            <?php previous_posts_link(__( 'Newer Entries <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'your-theme' )) ?>
         </div>

    </div><!-- #nav-below -->

<?php } //endif ( $total_pages > 1 )
```

And don't forget to use `wp_reset_postdata()` to reset the query after the necessary code block.